# MS Edge randomly does not load script

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have a server program written in Python, running on Windows 10.

I am testing it using Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 on the same machine.

This is the HTML page I send to the browser on receiving a connection -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>AccInABox/dev</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/init.css"/>
    <h1>Welcome to AccInABox</h1>
    <br/>
    <h2>Please wait ...</h2>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/on_load.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/dom-drag.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/actions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/bpmn.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/bpmn_defs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/bpmn_palette.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/gui_obj.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/aib_obj.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/ask_question.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/errmsg.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/sxml_popup.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/tree.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/menu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/grid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/grid_obj.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/toolbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/images.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/calendar.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="on_load();"></body>
</html>
```

This has been working fine for some time. But I have recently found that sometimes not all scripts are loaded. The behaviour is random - sometimes all are loaded, sometimes one or another is missing, but it varies.

I have put some debugging statements in my server program, and I can confirm that, when a script is missing, the server never receives the GET request.

I also test using Chrome and Firefox, and I have never experienced this problem with those.

Comment: try the Developer Console. you can view all network requests and their HTTP status codes. (never tried Edge, but it should be similar to F12 in Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: Frank, the main question is whether the requests are **sent**. If they were sent, then it seems to be an issue with the request, possibly a network issue, which happened to manifest when this was tested with Edge. You need to check whether the requests are sent in Edge.

Comment: I looked at Network in Dev Console. There is a lot of data and I am not sure what is relevant. Most have Status 200 OK, but some show Pending even though they seem to have been received. I have a case where 'gui_obj.js' was not received and the server did not receive a GET. In the Network log I can see 7 GET requests, all 'Pending'. In the Request Headers, the field contents are incremented for each request - e.g.  'Accept:' shows "/" for the first one, "/","/" for the second one, "/","/","/" for the third one, etc. Does this help? What else should I look for?

Comment: Try to clear Microsoft Edge browser data (cache, history and so on), or open the website in the InPrivate window. If still not working you could try to [reset browser setting or repair it](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-microsoft-edge-browser-to-default-settings-in-windows-10).

Comment: It turns out that there was a bug in my Python server program. I was sending a 'Keep-Alive' header, and then closing the connection after sending the file. Sorry about that.

Comment: Congratulation, you have solved the problem. If possible, I suggest you to post the solution, and mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding. ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was a bug in my server program.

I was sending a 'Connection: Keep-Alive' header, and then closing the connection after sending the file.

I now send a 'Connection: Close' header, and everything works perfectly.

Sorry about that.